# Validate XML document against XML schema in Go

Tags: xml, validation, go, xsd

How do you read an XML document in Go and validate it against an XML schema?

Answer (score 1):

A start vouwld be to use the project [**`metaleap/go-xsd`**](https://github.com/metaleap/go-xsd), which can generate Go "XML wrapper" package sources for specified XSD schema URIs.

> Each generated wrapper package contains the type structures required to easily `xml.Unmarshal()` an XML document based on that XSD.

It means that if you are *not* able to unmarshall an xml document using those generated classes (based on a specific XML schema), that xml document isn't a valid one (for that XML schema).

Comment: From my experience, this package is not suitable for xml validation against XSD, for example, it will not enforce element sequence in XML. because there is no concept of sequencing in Go struct.

Comment: @Lich interesting. Is there any package made to enforce element sequence in XML then?

Comment: My search today returned nothing written in Go, some Go packages wrapping other tools might do, (like: https://github.com/krolaw/xsd), but I have not test that personally, yet.

Comment: There is this lib: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/lestrrat/go-libxml2/xsd but it requires c libxml-2.0 I'm looking for a cleaner one. @VonC

Comment: @Totalys Good catch. I have not found any other Go library which would validate an XML against a schema.